# How to use DeleteFile with wildcard in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

How to use [DeleteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx) with wildcard?

so `c:\myFolder\a*.txt` will delete `a123.txt` and `a5555.txt` but not `b123.txt`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAW fd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(L"C:\\myFolder\\a*.txt", &fd);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        DeleteFileW((wstring(L"C:\\myFolder\\") + fd.cFileName).c_str());
    } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &fd));
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`DeleteFile()` does not support wildcards.

@user1438233 showed you how to use `DeleteFile()` in a `FindFirstFile()` loop to search for files using wildcards.

Another option is to use `SHFileOperation()` and let the Shell handle the wildcards for you:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCTW op = {0};
op.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
op.pFrom = L"C:\\myFolder\\a*.txt\0";
op.fFlags = FOF_FILESONLY | FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NORECURSION;

SHFileOperationW(&op);
```

Comment: yes, another option is to use: system("del C:\\myFolder\\a*.txt")

Comment: The documentation doesn't say, whether COM needs to be initialized on the calling thread. Do you happen to know, whether this is the case?